# SQL Left Join. Taking too long.

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, primary-key

Okay so here are my table schemas.
I have 2 tables. Say Table A and Table B. The primary key of Table A is PriKeyA bigint(50) and primary key of Table B is PriKeyB varchar(255). Both PriKeyA and PriKeyB contain the same type of data.
The relevant fields of Table A required for this problem are Last_login_date_in_A (date) and Table B is the primary key itself.
What I need to do is, get those PriKeyA's in A which are not there in Table B's PriKeyB column and the Last_login_date_in_A column should be greater than 30 days from the current date. Basically I need the difference of Table A and Table B along with a certain condition(which is the date in this problem)
Here is my SQL command

```
: SELECT A.PriKeyA from A  
 LEFT JOIN B ON A.PriKeyA = B.PriKeyB   
 WHERE B.PriKeyB IS NULL and DATEDIFF(CURRENTDATE,Last_login_date_in_A)>30;
```

However when I run this MySQL command, it takes about ridiculously long amount of time (About 3 hours). The size of Table A is 2,50,000 and Table B is 42,000 records respectively. I thought that this problem could arise due to the fact that PriKeyA and PriKeyB are different datatypes. So i also used the `CAST(PriKeyB as unsigned)` in the query. But that too didn't work. There was a marginal performance improvement.

What could be the possible problems? I've used Left Joins before and they never have taken this long.

Comment: I would suspect that the problem is with the datatypes, and specifically with performing the conversion on every row during the query.

Comment: But shouldn't the type casting have solved that?

Comment: Your db runs on hardware. There are no magic unicorns there, if you don't use at least InnoDB and if you don't optimize MySQL's settings then you're barking at the wrong tree. Also, always use `EXPLAIN` when you wonder why something takes too long and MySQL will tell you what it thinks it should do while extrapolating data you asked for.

Comment: @OleGooner The cast/conversion is done at every comparison, with 2500000*42000 comparisons (minus the ones the optimizer can shave off via the other conditions), there'll be a few conversions...

Comment: You could create a temporary table with the conversion done ahead of time that you can do the join on, for the smaller table that'd only result in 47k casts. Indexed computed columns won't work on MySQL sadly :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expense of the query appears to be for these reasons:

- The SQL datatype for A's PK and B's PK aren't the same.
- Table A probably doesn't have an index on Last_login_date_in_A

What this means is that ALL rows in table A MUST be examined one row at a time in order to determine if the > 30 days ago criteria is true. This is especially true if A has 2,500,000 rows (as evidenced by how you placed your commas in A's row count) instead of 250,000.

Adding an index on Last_login_date_in_A might help you out here, but will also slightly slow down insert/update/delete statement times for the table due to needing to update the additional index.

Additionally, you should utilize the documentation for explaining MySQL's actual chosen query plan for your query at: [MySQL query plan documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)

Comment: It's 2,50,000. That's how it's written in India.